# Relative path problem for a deployed win32 application

Tags: c++, file, path, relative-path

I have written a c++ program and deployed it in say `c:\my_app`, and my executable's path is `c:\my_app\my_app.exe`. Say, my_app needs many files such as `the_file.txt`, which is located in `c:\my_app\the_file.txt`.

In my executable, I open the txt file as, `xx.open("the_file.txt");`

Moreover, I have associated my program with let's say .myp extension.

When I'm on Desktop, and want to open a file named example.myp, my program can not see `the_file.txt`. Because, it (somehow) assumes that it's currently working on Desktop.

Is there any easy way to handle this problem by changing shell command for open in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`? The naive solution would be to change all file open operations with something like `%my_app_location/the_file.txt"`. I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 5):

*Always* use a full path name to open a file.  In other words, don't open "foo.txt", open "c:\bar\foo.txt".  To find the install directory of your EXE use GetModuleFileName(), passing NULL for the module handle.

Answer (score 1):

These days you shouldn't add files to c:\my_app....
Instead use the ProgramData Folder and full paths.

Use SHGetSpecialFolderPathA with CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA to get the ProgramData folder and the create your program directory and add your files.

Answer (score 0):

You should set current directory for your app's folder with [SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365530%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function. After that you can open file by name without full path